# how to make JPG image transparent background?

Tags: image, format, jpeg

As we all know that jpg image format does not support transparency.
so we use .png  format.

i was surfing on net and i found an image with .jpg format and
transparent. it is wonder how a jpg format image can be transparent.

here is the example image.
http://bdthemes.net/demo/joomla/intensy/images/sampledata/features/top_b.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided example image is in fact not a JPEG, but a png file.
It has the extension and mime-type of a jpeg file, but it's contents are in png format.

JPEG file format does not support transparacy.

So if you need transparancy in images for use in browsers.
You can either:

- convert the image to png, this works in all browsers
- use [ZorroSVG](http://quasimondo.com/ZorroSVG/), requires SVG support but results in smaller files for photographic images.
- use webp, only use when you have fallbacks in place for browsers that do not support webp.

Answer (score 2):

The new [JPEG-XR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XR#Capabilities) standard supports transparency.

However, this is not a real JPG, it's a PNG. If you rename it to `.txt`, you can see that the contents of the file start with `PNG`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check its mime type, it must be renamed .png to .jpg